# AWS ETL Glue job

Tags: aws-glue

Using GLUE ETL jobs would like to create data catalog table and load objects which are in s3 (partitioned) like below. Table would be 'data1'

s3://test/data1/2022/03/22/1.csv
s3://test/data1/2022/03/23/2.csv
s3://test/data1/2022/04/08/1.csv
s3://test/data1/2022/04/09/2.csv

> S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
> format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": False, "separator": ","},
> connection_type="s3",
> format="csv",
> connection_options={
> "paths": ["s3://test/data1"],
> "recurse": True,
> },
> transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1", )
>
> ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
> frame=S3bucket_node1, mappings=[], transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2" )
>
> DataCatalogtable_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
> frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
> database="default",
> table_name="data1",
> additional_options={
> "enableUpdateCatalog": True,
> "updateBehavior": "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
> "partitionKeys": ["partition_0", "partition_1", "partition_2"],
> },
> transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node3", )*

***py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.getCatalogSink.
: com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.EntityNotFoundException: Table pk_datacdr_new not found. (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityNotFoundException; Request ID: 07a1ec53-2ade-4b9f-a23f-36564dde19d8; Proxy: null)***

ETL glue job fails as the script expects table to be existing. Is there way to create table if not exists, please let me know?